# Visual Studio SignTool.exe Not Found

Tags: publish, signtool

I have completed an application I have made in Visual Studio 14.0, but when  I tried to publish the program, I get an error as Visual Studio cannot find 'SignTool.exe'. I have searched my Hard drive a few times for this but it is nowhere on my PC. Can anyone help me find it or download it?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I have a windows 7 and installing the ClickOnce Tools was not enough.

The `signtool.exe` appeared after also installing the sdk:

[image: selection in vs 2015]

Answer (score 205):

I had the same issue but installing the Windows 8.1 SDK as per [Catquatwa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31835311/4835543) did not work for me (signtool.exe was still missing from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vX\Bin).

I stumbled across this solution: http://www.benedykt.net/2015/08/12/missing-signtool-exe-w-visual-studio-2015/

Basically, for VS 2015, this would be:

- Open Programs and Features
- Select "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015" and click "Change"
- Press "Modify" to progress to Features options
- Select "Windows and Web Development", then tick "ClickOnce Publishing Tools" for installation
- Then "Next" and then "Update"

Comment: If you install visual studio 2015 Pro from an MSDN Subscription the installer doesn't ask you for options.  It just installs basic c# etc so you need to do this to install anything else you want, including publishing tools.

Comment: Same case when Unity installs it; no options shown.

Comment: This worked for me.  I just ran the installer again, selected "Modify" and checked the box for  "ClickOnce Publishing Tools".  Thanks!

Answer (score 97):

If you do not care about sign your program when you publish, just right click your project then choose **Properties** --> **Signing** --> **un-check Sign the ClickOnce manifest** . I had the same issue when building my program on another machine which did not have ClickOne.

Comment: Important to emphasize:  need to make sure it's right-clicking the project and not the top Solution indicator.  Selecting Properties on the Solution indicator gives me an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

Comment: Just as a side note, ClickOnce is there for security purposes so you should be very careful when disabling that.

Comment: was looking for this

Answer (score 63):

The [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx) is available as part of the Windows SDK (which comes with [Visual Studio Community 2015](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=526729)). Make sure to select the "**ClickOnce Publishing Tools**" from the feature list during the installation of Visual Studio 2015 to get the SignTool.

Once Visual Studio is installed you can run the `signtool` command from the [Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx). By default (on Windows 10) the SignTool will be installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe`.

**ClickOnce Publishing Tools Installation:**

[image]

**SignTool Location:**

[image]

Comment: also may be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64` (ox x86)

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and I didn't find this option.

Comment: Thanks. I found it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\arm64

Answer (score 12):

1.Just Disable **signing** from the properties of your project it will solve issue :)

2.The other method is to purchase the certificate for your product from Digicert or Comodo or any other you want. You can get some free certificates for One pc use.

Comment: How is this any different from Hua Trung's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33982816/369450)?

Comment: i have just answered the question that is have tried once. He is also right if he gives the same answer

Comment: Ha ha ha!

He submitted that answer in November 2015. You gave the same answer in February 2017  :-D

Comment: This is still a horrible idea security wise

Comment: @Jeremy then add a sign in Certificate instead there are multiple free certificates for this purpose or create a dummy by yourself . If you have professional product then just purchase from any other like digicert or any other certification company

Answer (score 10):

No Worries! I have found the solution! I just installed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx
and it all worked fine :)

Comment: @ralphspoon I'm not sure. I have tried it on windows 10, so it should work on windows 8, but I don't know about windows 7

Comment: But for installing this 1.5 GB space is required. is this the right one?

Answer (score 6):

Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=323507

Right click on Project, select properties and Un-Check the sign on option in teh project save and re-built.

This has fixed issue for me.

Comment: @cpburnz: This is specific with the SDK kit for 8.1 where I have provided the link to download the .exe file which solved my issue, where I accept Trung's answer step is same but the SDK is not required to install in his method and this is SDK specific. I tried lot many option and finally resolved this, so thought to share to help who ever face similar issue. The Trung's answer was 2015 and I got similar issue recently.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of `Can anyone help me find it or download it?` You are completely bypassing signing altogether.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677797/4469739) is a solution for Visual Studio 2017. The installer looks a littlebit different from the VS 2015 version and the name of the installation packages are different.