# "SignTool.exe not found" when debugging in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fody-costura

I was writing a simple program in Visual Studio that requires an external library. When I debug it everything went smoothly.

Since I want to distribute the exe alone without the dlls, I installed Costura, clear all the previous builds and then press debug. Strangely the error "SignTool.exe not found" error pops out. However I am not publishing the exe, I am just trying to build it, how come this error will pop out?

Even after I uninstalled Costura, this problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `Costura` modifies your project to require signing. If you don't care about signing, you can [disable/revert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833142/visual-studio-signtool-exe-not-found/33982816#33982816).

It seems that `SignTool.exe` is not installed by default for VS2015, but you can [add it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833142/visual-studio-signtool-exe-not-found).