# Visual studio gives build error: SignTool was not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that was working fine until yesterday. When I was trying to debug it a message popped up that there are errors even though I can't see anything.

Build message shows this info:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3616,5): error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe was not found at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\signtool.exe.
```

You will probably say I have to download this SignTool but how come everything was working fine earlier and now I need this tool?

Comment: Are you working with other people? Could they have added something that you retrieved from Source Control? If you didn't change anything, then closing and restarting Visual Studio, possibly rebooting could help

Comment: Have a look at the answers for this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833142/visual-studio-signtool-exe-not-found

Comment: @krillgar thats the thing. Thats my pc, i didnt change anything, i was working on other project when this happend. So i restarted VS and even pc and tried old project to check if i will be able to work on it. It didnt help.

Comment: You didn't happen to uninstall the Windows SDK?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - no, i didnt install or uninstall anything lately.

Answer (score -3):

Here is solution for you problem ,

I hope it will work,

1. Click on Project Properties ,
2. check for signing options
3. Uncheck all sign the assembly
4. Clean the Solution and Build it should work!.

Comment: Stop signing a signed assembly because the sign tool is missing is making this worse in my opinion.

Comment: I already had sign the assembly unchecked, so thats not the case