# How do I reverse this? - "An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, rebuild

I mistakenly clicked on Publish Now in Project > Properties > Publish.

It gave me the error -

> An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found

But I do not want to publish anything, nor do I want to install "ClickOnce Publishing Tools".

I am unable to rebuild normal EXEs. How do I reverse this?

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot as requested]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio SignTool.exe Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833142/visual-studio-signtool-exe-not-found)

Comment: This question has been asked before, here's where it can be found. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833142/visual-studio-signtool-exe-not-found

Comment: @MatthewKaulfers - as I mentioned, this is not a duplicate. I DO NOT WANT TO INSTALL ClickOnce nor do I want to PUBLISH. I just want to go back to rebuilding the EXE by clicking on Build - Rebuild Solution. But it does not allow me to do so anymore.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot for clarity.

Comment: It likely updated something in your project file. Can you simply rollback that file?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - could you please tell me where the project file is located and how to roll it back. Sorry if it seems elementary but I am new to this thing.

Comment: You are not using a version control system (SVN or GIT for example)? If not, you would need to open the project properties and see if the ClickOnce option is set in the Publish tab.

Comment: I assume you meant Debug > Properties. In the Publish tab, I could not find the said option. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to Publish or install ClickOnce, do the following:

- Go to `Project > Properties`
- In the `Signing` tab, uncheck `Sign the ClickOnce manifests`.

That's all.